# SQL Server 2017 Availability group not routing to secondary server

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2017

I've set up a dev AlwaysOn environment on SSMS 2017. 
I have my AG set up:

[image]

[image]

I also ran the following scripts:

```
ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP [DEV-SQLAG] MODIFY REPLICA ON N'DEV-DB1' WITH (SECONDARY_ROLE (READ_ONLY_ROUTING_URL = N'TCP://Dev-DB1.test.com:5022'));

ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP [DEV-SQLAG] MODIFY REPLICA ON N'DEV-DB2' WITH (SECONDARY_ROLE (READ_ONLY_ROUTING_URL = N'TCP://Dev-DB2.test.com:5022'));

ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP [DEV-SQLAG] MODIFY REPLICA ON N'DEV-DB1' WITH (PRIMARY_ROLE (READ_ONLY_ROUTING_LIST = ('DEV-DB2','DEV-DB1')));

ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP [DEV-SQLAG] MODIFY REPLICA ON N'DEV-DB2' WITH (PRIMARY_ROLE (READ_ONLY_ROUTING_LIST = ('DEV-DB1','DEV-DB2')));
```

now when I connect to the listener (using SSMS2017) with ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly and I run select `@@SERVERNAME` it still shows me DEV-DB1. I thought it would show me that I'm getting data from the secondary DEV-DB2

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you please try this from a command line?  `--sqlcmd -S listenerName -E -d databaseName -K ReadOnly -Q "Select @@servername"`

Comment: still comes back with ------------------ DEV-DB1

Comment: CORRECTION: the -K readOnly is causing an error. the rest of the script (when ran without the -K) returns DEV-DB1. with the -K I get an error "Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server".

Comment: What error as you getting?

Comment: when I run sqlcmd -S DEV-Listener -E -d devdb -K readOnly -Q "Select @@servername" the command prompt returns a long error "Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : Client unable to establish connection because an error was encountered during handshakes before login...."

Comment: when I run: sqlcmd -S DEV-Listener -E -d devdb -Q "Select @@servername". I get the name of the server

Comment: Looks like you have other problems, did you check all the logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my issue: I was under the impression that my End Point URL should be the same as my routing URL, which was going to port 5022. after reading the following article [read_only_routing_url](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattn/2012/04/25/calculating-read_only_routing_url-for-alwayson/) I was able to identify my actual routing URL port which was 1433.

Answer (score 0):

2 more things to be noted here while you are trying to connect to the Listener via the Management Studio for ReadOnly routing:

- Make sure that you are also providing the database Name along with "ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly" in the Additional Connection parameters section of SSMS
- SSMS sometimes has sticky connections so it could be possible that it is still connecting to an existing connection that was made via SSMS before providing the parameters "ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly". Try restarting the SSMS.

Comment: I'm not sure about the first bullet point but I did try restarting both instances. Didn't help.

Comment: Regarding the first bullet point, you'll need to add the following parameters in the additional Connection parameters section of SSMS: "ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly;Database=Db1". And about the second point, you need to restart the management studio (SSMS) to avoid the sticky connections.